# Allow current draw only when it is over a certain value

Tags: current, circuit-design, current-limiting, fuses

Is there a way to passively allow the current to flow over a certain amount? i.e., if it is a small parasitic drain, ignore it, but if it is something larger like starting an engine, allow it. Almost a reverse fuse?

I realize this could be done with a microcontroller but I am hoping/looking for something passive + efficient.

Comment: You don't know how much current will be drawn in advance

Comment: An current-carrying NTC?

Comment: How will your circuit start if it doesn't allow any current to flow? The big current start as zero current.

Comment: You want something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vJaFc.png). Periodically, just close the spring loaded switch with your finger. If it sticks closed, then you have enough of a load (if you design the relay/spring correctly.) If it doesn't stay closed, and just opens back up, then you don't have enough of a load. Remove the load and the switch opens, too. Your circuit will have to work something like this concept (though not necessarily that way): periodically sampling the load current.

Comment: Not possible (microcontroller or not) (you need to flow current to know how much current flows...) unless some new laws of physic comes around, but if you explain what you'd like to do, there are probably some other ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Simulated]
I have made a possible solution. I don't know if this would work for you, but let me explain the principle behind it.
We know your load is 10Ohm (assumption, at 12V it means the load will need 1,2A). The voltage drop across 10Ohm is neglible. But when the load is 1k, the voltage drop is 11,6V-ish.
We set a setpoint with R3 and R4. Where if the voltage after the load is less then 8.5V the comparator will output 5V. The gate of the Pmos will be high, so inactive.
This is a very crude solution, where many unknowns need to be known, but there is potentional for it to possibly work. If we could have more information we could possibly fine-tune this solution or look for something else.